# how to trigger eventemitter after http is done in angular2

Tags: angular

I have these two set in a component.

```
  cards$: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  private cards: Array<Cards>;
```

When i run the http.get below, how do i trigger cards$.emit(this.cards);

```
  this.cards = [];
  http.get('http://myendpoint')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => {this.cards = res };
```

Answer (score 4):

Just like you said `cards$.emit(this.cards);`. Add this to your subscribe `onNext()` callback:

```
http.get('http://myendpoint')
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.cards = res;
    this.cards$.emit(this.cards);
  };
```

You also should subscribe to it somewhere else to use this value, for example:

```
constructor() {
  this.cards$.subscribe(c => console.log(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a complete callback:

```ts
  this.cards = [];

  http.get('http://myendpoint')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
       res => { this.cards = res }, 
       error => { console.log(error) },
       () => this.cards$.emit(this.cards));
```

This way works if you expect more than one event and want to execute code after the last event. From `Http` you'll only get one event and in this case @Sasxa s approach is probably easier.

Comment: I looked it up here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4e5cd1e558503aec87dd95e59337b31f261c941f/modules/angular2/src/facade/async.ts#L40, but it's nice if this works as positional arguments as well. Learned something new about tS :)

Comment: hm, I didn't even know you could send callbacks as object (: thanks for the tip!

Comment: I guess the advantage is, this way you can omit arguments like I did with `error` before your edit.